# ActivityResultContracts TakePicture it is always returning false as a result

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-camera

I'm using Jetpack Compose, and when I call the method to take a picture with the camera, the result of `ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture` is always false.

Sample code:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun SomeScreen() {
    val photoUri by remember { mutableStateOf(value = Uri.EMPTY) }

    val cameraLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(),
        onResult = { success ->
            if (success) {
                println("success")
                println("photo uri: $photoUri")
            } else println("result failed")
        }
    )

    val cameraPermissionState = rememberPermissionState(
        permission = Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        onPermissionResult = { granted ->
            if (granted) cameraLauncher.launch(photoUri)
            else print("camera permission is denied")
        }
    )

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Button(onClick = cameraPermissionState::launchPermissionRequest) {
            Text(text = "Take a photo with Camera")
        }
    }
}
```

I used the `accompanist-permissions` library to make it easier, the part of opening the camera app and taking the photo is apparently working normally, but the result from `cameraLauncher` is always false...

Can anyone guide me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are passing an `empty Uri` to `launch`, and the Camera app can't save the image in that `Uri`. If you open the `TakePicture` class or place the mouse cursor over it, you will see the following information:

> An ActivityResultContract to take a picture saving it into the
> provided content-Uri. Returns true if the image was saved into the
> given Uri.

In other words, the `TakePicture` class will not automatically create a `File` for you, you will have to create a `File` yourself and provide the `Uri`.

I'll assume a simple scenario where you want to take a photo for some temporary task within the app. To achieve this goal, you need to understand some steps that are missing in your code:

1. As you need to create a `File` and expose it to the Camera app, you need to create rules with the [File Provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) and declare it in the `Manifest` file.
2. The function that creates a `File` and exposes its `Uri` with the `FileProvider`.

Lets start with `file_paths.xml` (inside *res/xml*):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <cache-path
        name="cache_pictures"
        path="/" />

</paths>
```

I'm using `cache-path` here following the idea of keeping the files temporarily.

In the `Manifest` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application ...>

        <activity .../>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Extension to create a `File` and return a `Uri`:

```kotlin
fun Context.createTempPictureUri(
    provider: String = "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider",
    fileName: String = "picture_${System.currentTimeMillis()}",
    fileExtension: String = ".png"
): Uri {
    val tempFile = File.createTempFile(
        fileName, fileExtension, cacheDir
    ).apply {
        createNewFile()
    }

    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(applicationContext, provider, tempFile)
}
```

The cache folder is being used in this example with `cacheDir`. If changing here to `filesDir`, be sure to change in the `cache-path` on `file_paths.xml` to `files-path`.

Now in `Composable Screen` you can have something like this:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun SomeScreen() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var currentPhotoUri by remember { mutableStateOf(value = Uri.EMPTY) }
    var tempPhotoUri by remember { mutableStateOf(value = Uri.EMPTY) }

    val cameraLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(),
        onResult = { success ->
            if (success) currentPhotoUri = tempPhotoUri
        }
    )

    val cameraPermissionState = rememberPermissionState(
        permission = Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        onPermissionResult = { granted ->
            if (granted) {
                tempPhotoUri = context.createTempPictureUri()
                cameraLauncher.launch(tempPhotoUri)
            } else print("camera permission is denied")
        }
    )

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        AnimatedVisibility(visible = currentPhotoUri.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
            // from coil library 
            AsyncImage(
                modifier = Modifier.size(size = 240.dp),
                model = currentPhotoUri,
                contentDescription = null
            )
        }

        Button(onClick = cameraPermissionState::launchPermissionRequest) {
            Text(text = "Take a photo with Camera")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need camera permission for take picture

Comment: @Demigod you are wrong, you will get the exception                                                                                                    **java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity clip={text/uri-list hasLabel(0) {U(content)}} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{b1271ab 32567:package/u0a195} (pid=32567, uid=10195) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA**